# Hosting SQL in Azure and Website on different hosting provider

Tags: http, security, azure, https

**Situation**

So I'm thinking about building ASP.NET Core website to host it on Linux based hosting provider. But I still want to use MSSQL database, so best choice for that would be Microsoft Azure.

**My Question**

Now my question is rather security based, since I know, that hosting them on different providers is totally possible ([Regarding this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688913/can-i-host-an-application-in-windows-azure-and-have-the-database-stored-on-diffe))

But if I'm about to do so, then how will be my data encrypted? If I'm about to use default HTTP protocol, then I asume, it's not, but if to use HTTPS protocol, it should be encrypted as well? Or how would it work, do I need to setup some other protocols or security for that matter?

**My Thoughts**

Since Client won't be directly connected with Web Site to Database connection, then there is not chance, that this connection would be listened, yet this "might not be listened" is rather not a far chance. And if HTTPS is included, then all connections should be encrypted, then it should work same with Web Server to Database connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can access Azure SQL from anywhere as long as IP address is in the firewall rule. Since communication to Azure SQL is on ***SSL/TCP*** at all times, data is already encrypted.

Ideally, you want to host Azure SQL and web application in ***same region*** not to mention same provider. The main reason is your website will be dramatically slow due to network latency, if you host those in different location.

Recently, Azure offers [App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-intro). It is definitely worth the try, before considering an alternative route.

***FYI:*** *Web Apps on Linux does not yet support deployment of .NET Core apps from uncompiled source. You need to publish/compile your .NET Core app locally first, and then push the published site bits to your app.*

Comment: Alright, as I understand then, I don't need any kind of certificate for connection to be secure. What I forgot to mention is, that one of the main reasons I want different Web Provider is ability to have Mail client enabled.  Maybe it is possible in Azure, but didn't find it at that time.

Comment: `I don't need any kind of certificate for connection to be secure` You are correct. For for SMTP service, you might want to look at [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/solutions/).